# Screenshot of the device screen Android from service

Tags: java, android, service, background

I am working on an Android application This application is a parental advisor application and it will be installed on the parents' phone and on the child's phone.
My question is how will the screenshot be taken from the boy's phone without his knowledge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats pretty high privilege, which need special permissions. you probably have to create [`AccessibilityService`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service), but be aware, that Google Play may refuse your app from publish in their store. btw. you can't start this `Service` from the code, user must enable it in system Settings

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you have an idea how to take a screenshot with time?
The time will be set by the parents.

Comment: use [`AlarmManager`](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms) or `WorkManager`(https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) for scheduling actions. you may also leave some timer inside created `AccessibilityService`

Comment: I'll take a look. Thank you very much for helping me